# How can I cast a DataTable, to a List or ArrayList of another type of object

Tags: java, arraylist, datatable

I have a `DataTable` object which I need to cast to `List<ScParametrics>` and save the list to a database using Hibernate.

The warning is `DataTable cannot be cast to java.util.List`

```
public static addParamDataTable(DataTable listDataTable) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    List<ScParametrics> list = (List) listDataTable;
    for (Iterator<ScParametrics> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        ScParametrics scParametrics = it.next();
        session.saveOrUpdate(scParametrics);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library or something? AFAIK, DataTable doesn't exist in Java. I'm assuming it's either a library or a custom class, in which case we'd need the code from it.

Comment: Im using, Jfs, Primefaces and Hibernate, thats all. There is a class call DataTable but doesn´t have DataRow like .net

Comment: I dont know if im wrong but this is the class that i use : public class DataTable extends UIData implements Widget, RTLAware, ClientBehaviorHolder

Answer (score -1):

If you are casting something into a list like that you need to be casting the typeof the list not the list.

List list = (ScParametrics) listDataTable;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that have a warning "inconvertible types" required ScParametrics and founds a Datatable